# I am trying to make a search input inside a SVG image in my website, how can I do that?

Tags: html, forms, svg, input

I am trying to use a SVG file as a container to my web page header, but I don't now how embed a search input in SVG file; any one can help me?
Actualy my question is, is there a way to use input element inside SVG file code?
I want to make full SVG front end for my site; if I can.

Comment: make the input position absolute and move it over the svg element

Comment: Thanks, I guess this solution will  work for html input positioning on SVG, but is there a way to use input element in SVG file code?

Comment: Maybe inside a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)